# How to set useState to choose only one Color

Tags: reactjs, function, tailwind-css, use-state

I got a list 3 div's with a background of different colors , if i clicked on one of them the function will set the State to true which will render a tick icon that is nested inside the div , but i can only choose one color , how i can modify the code so if i clicked on one div the states for that div will be true and the tick icon will appear but it will disappear from the other div's (if previously selected).

[image]

```
const [colorPick, setColorPick] = useState(false);

const colorPickHandler = () => {
    setColorPick(!colorPick);
  }; 

<button className="cursor-pointer" onClick={colorPickHandler}>
              <div className="mt-3 border-2 border-solid border-black bg-red-600 w-8 h-8">
                {colorPick && (
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    className="h-6 w-6"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    stroke-width="2"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      d="M5 13l4 4L19 7"
                    />
                  </svg>
                )}
              </div>
            </button>
<button className="cursor-pointer" onClick={colorPickHandler}>
              <div className="mt-3 border-2 border-solid border-black bg-blue-600 w-8 h-8">
                {colorPick && (
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    className="h-6 w-6"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    stroke-width="2"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      d="M5 13l4 4L19 7"
                    />
                  </svg>
                )}
              </div>
            </button>
<button className="cursor-pointer" onClick={colorPickHandler}>
              <div className="mt-3 border-2 border-solid border-black bg-pink-600 w-8 h-8">
                {colorPick && (
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    className="h-6 w-6"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    stroke-width="2"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      d="M5 13l4 4L19 7"
                    />
                  </svg>
                )}
              </div>
            </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

colourPick should be a string, not a Boolean

It should take on the values of “red”, “blue”, or “brown”

So you can do something like colourPick === “red” && renderSvg

Answer (score 0):

You can define the state like an object for all the 3 colors. Like,

```
state = {red:false, blue:false, yellow:false};
```

```
if (e.target.name === 'red') setState = { red:true, blue:false, yellow:false }
else if (e.target.name === 'blue') setState = { red:false, blue:true, yellow:false };
else if (e.target.name === 'yellow') setState = { red:false, blue:false, yellow:true }
```

> Here you need to pass `e` parameter in the ColorPicker(e) function.

And add  `name="red"` to red button and respectively for others.